# Visual Treemap in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, data-visualization, treemap

Are there any frameworks for building squarified treemaps in C# 2.0 WinForms?

Something similar to this:

[image]

(from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/treemaps.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Research put one together.

Don't know how easy it is use.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/dda33e92-f0e8-4961-baaa-98160a006c27/default.aspx

Comment: It's easy to use.  It's written in .Net 1.1 (Arraylists and all) and the UI is pretty basic:  http://www.mises.org/images4/lastknightcloud.gif

Comment: @DavidVeksler : dead link

Answer (score 3):

I know you asked about WinForms, but I'm sure someone will hit this page when searching for WPF tree maps.  This currently seems to be the best WPF freebie out there, though I found a few minor issues with it, it's still pretty good:

http://treemaps.codeplex.com/

Comment: +1 Great find! I was going to write my own TreemapPanel based on the squarify method, but now I don't have to!

Answer (score 0):

Check [Janus Grid Ex](http://www.janusys.com/controls/) should have a tree view...

UPDATE: http://www.avizsoft.com/treemap.htm

WinChart™ - Adds Tree Map Chart Type
http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/whatsnew20082.aspx

Comment: My understanding is that there is a big difference between a tree-view and a tree-map